# Strange results after Solidify

Tags: mesh

I made this mesh and checked it for Scale, Doubles and Merge by distance.

The mesh is 1 whole, but as you can see in photo 3, the top is on it instead of in and on photo 2 you see cracks at the bottom left.

In my opinion it is, first make the mesh and then Solidify, but when I solidify it, this mesh I get the strangest results.

What am I doing wrong" ?

[image: Foto 1]

[image: Foto 2]

[image: Foto 3]

Comment: Can u provide blend file?

Comment: maybe your normals are inverted, in that case select all and press Shift N. For the cylinder, it may be inavoidable as faces can overlap, but there are some options that you could try in the modifier. Maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 4):

The "cracks" might be due to overlapping geometry which can happen in corners where faces are extended towards each other so far that they start intersecting. This is something that you cannot really avoid especially with high resolution geometry, because than the space between edges and vertices gets smaller. You can set *Thickness Clamp* in the modifier, but that leads to thinner walls in those areas.

The faces extending in the wrong direction might be due to an incorrect face orientation. If you enable *Face Orientation* in the *Show Overlays* menu at the bottom right of the *3D Viewport* window, you will see blue and red faces. Blue is considered the outside, red the inside. In the *Solidify Modifier*, the *Offset* value of -1 extends to the inside, 0 equally inside and outside and 1 in the outwards direction.

Another thing you might want to enable in the modifier is *Even Thickness*. Without it, the solidification turns to decrease and increase thickness towards corners and borders, what becomes very obvious when using higher *Thickness* values.

Here's a screenshot where to check the *Face Orientation*:

[image: face orientation]